# Evaluting $\lim_{(x,y) \to(0,0)} x \cdot \ln{(x^2+2y^2)}$

Tags: limits

How can I find such limit:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} x \cdot \ln{(x^2+2y^2)}$$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using polar coordinates $x=\rho \cos \phi$ and $y=\rho \sin \phi$ we have

$$|\log (x^2+2y^2)|=|\log \rho^2(1+\sin^2 \phi)|\le 2|\log \rho|+|\log 2|$$

and

$|x|\le \rho$

Therefore,

$$|x\log(x^2+2y^2)|\le \rho \left(2|\log \rho|+|\log 2|\right)\to 0$$

as $\rho \to 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If $x=0$ then our product is $0$. If $x\ne 0$ and $(x,y)$ is close enough to $(0,0)$, then $x^2+2y^2\lt 1$, and therefore $|\ln(x^2+2y^2)|\le |\ln(x^2)|$.

Comment: I got lost: the logarithmic function is monotonic ascending ,so $\;x^2\le x^2+2y^2\implies \log x^2\le\log(x^2+2y^2)\;$ , no matter whether the point is close to $\;(0,0)\;$ or not. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, the something is the absolute value signs, which makes a difference since below $1$ the log is negative. We have for example $1/2\gt 1/5$ ($x^2+2y^2\gt x^2$) but $|\ln(1/2)|\lt |\ln(1/5)|$.

Comment: Of course. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. I agree that it looked backwards, But negative numbers are weird, , that's why I go to positives as soon as I can.